# Convert hex to corresponding bit

Tags: c#, binary, hex

I have created a textfile to store some data retrieved from database.

This is my code.

```
CreateFile(String.Format("{0}\\U{1:X8}_C{2}_F{3}_B{4:X16}.TXT", 
                               userDir, 
                               staffWeaponEntity.StaffID.Oid, 
                               capsensepw, 
                               fingerprintID,
                               staffWeaponEntity.WeaponID.WeaponTypeID.Oid));
```

This is my output

```
".\\Data\\Tmp\\00000004\\USER\\U00000002_C000000_F00000000_B0000000000000004.TXT"
```

I would like to convert the last value which is 00000004 to bit pattern binary value which is 0000000000001000. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Convert.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a base (in this case base 2), and [`String.PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) to add the padding zeros.

```
CreateFile(String.Format("{0}\\U{1:X8}_C{2}_F{3}_B{4}.TXT", 
    userDir, 
    staffWeaponEntity.StaffID.Oid, 
    capsensepw, 
    fingerprintID,
    Convert.ToString(staffWeaponEntity.WeaponID.WeaponTypeID.Oid, 2).PadLeft(16, '0'));
```

Also, `4` in binary is `100`, not `1000`.

---

**EDIT**

It seems you just want the corresponding bit lit up. We can use [bit shifting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1sway8w.aspx) for this. Keep in mind the value you are using must be between 1 and 16.

```
CreateFile(String.Format("{0}\\U{1:X8}_C{2}_F{3}_B{4}.TXT", 
    userDir, 
    staffWeaponEntity.StaffID.Oid, 
    capsensepw, 
    fingerprintID,
    Convert.ToString(1 << (staffWeaponEntity.WeaponID.WeaponTypeID.Oid - 1), 2).PadLeft(16, '0'));
```

Comment: I have tried this way but this only works when my value is 4. When my hex value turns into 7. I will get 0000000000000101 instead.

Comment: @active92 Are you sure? I get `111` for 7. `101` in binary is 5.

Comment: i need it to be in big pattern binary value which means 1= 0000000000000001, 2=0000000000000010, 3= 0000000000000100 and so on

Comment: Neither I nor Google seem to know what *big pattern binary* means, so kindly explain. You example shows a binary value padded with zeros up to 16 places.

Comment: Oh I see, you want the corresponding bit.

Comment: ya. sorry for the bad explanation and wording used.

Comment: Updated the answer.